# How can I get solar system body mass/radius in Python?

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, astroquery

Can I use Astroquery/Astropy to get the radius and mass of solar system objects? Or another common library?

I've been trying to use astroquery.horizons

I've tried elements() and ephemeris() but no dice, they don't contain columns for mass or radius. The only place I could find the values (and others, see below) is in the raw API response:

```py
from astroquery.jplhorizons import Horizons
from astropy import units as u

object_id = "199" # Mercury
obj_id = Horizons(id=obj, id_type="majorbody", location="0") # Location 0 is the solar system barycenter

response = obj_id.ephemerides_async(get_raw_response=True)
```

Produces

```plaintext
API VERSION: 1.2
API SOURCE: NASA/JPL Horizons API

*******************************************************************************
 Revised: April 12, 2021             Mercury                            199 / 1

 PHYSICAL DATA (updated 2021-Apr-12):
  Vol. Mean Radius (km) =  2440+-1        Density (g cm^-3)     = 5.427
  Mass x10^23 (kg)      =     3.302       Volume (x10^10 km^3)  = 6.085  
  Sidereal rot. period  =    58.6463 d    Sid. rot. rate (rad/s)= 0.00000124001
  Mean solar day        =   175.9421 d    Core radius (km)      = ~1600 
  Geometric Albedo      =     0.106       Surface emissivity    = 0.77+-0.06
  GM (km^3/s^2)         = 22031.86855     Equatorial radius, Re = 2440 km
  GM 1-sigma (km^3/s^2) =                 Mass ratio (Sun/plnt) = 6023682
  Mom. of Inertia       =     0.33        Equ. gravity  m/s^2   = 3.701     
  Atmos. pressure (bar) = < 5x10^-15      Max. angular diam.    = 11.0"   
  Mean Temperature (K)  = 440             Visual mag. V(1,0)    = -0.42 
  Obliquity to orbit[1] =  2.11' +/- 0.1' Hill's sphere rad. Rp = 94.4 
  Sidereal orb. per.    =  0.2408467 y    Mean Orbit vel.  km/s = 47.362 
  Sidereal orb. per.    = 87.969257  d    Escape vel. km/s      =  4.435
                                 Perihelion  Aphelion    Mean
  Solar Constant (W/m^2)         14462       6278        9126
  Maximum Planetary IR (W/m^2)   12700       5500        8000
  Minimum Planetary IR (W/m^2)   6           6           6
*******************************************************************************
... More Lines Below
```

This is really hard to extract data from, being two columns of text with no clear delimiter.

- Is there a good way to get mass/radius?

Also

- Is there a better way to get the true ID for bodies by name (getting results for their barycenter which isn't useful)

Comment: I know I can just manually hardcode these values.
But it seems like there should be a general way to do it, so I could hypothetically find the mass/radius of any small/major body by name.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Neither ephemerides() nor elements() contain the mass and radius.
https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/astroquery.jplhorizons.HorizonsClass.html#astroquery.jplhorizons.HorizonsClass.ephemerides
https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/astroquery.jplhorizons.HorizonsClass.html#astroquery.jplhorizons.HorizonsClass.elements

The only place I can find them is in the raw, human-readable plaintext, API response.

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/xgbn64/best_way_to_make_all_this_text_into_a_struct/

Seems like its pretty impossible. I tried using requests but ran into a similar problem, the json is just "signature" and "result".

Comment: Astropy appears to have [constants for earth, jupiter and the sun](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/constants/index.html#module-astropy.constants). Since the solar system only has 8 planets, can't you just _hard code_ it in a dictionary  with the data?  `planets = [{"id": 190, "name": "mercury", "mass": 3.3e23, "radius": 2.439e6}]` and so on....

Comment: There is a CSV file [link](https://dataherb.github.io/flora/planets_in_solar_system/)

Comment: astroquery's JPL Horizons interface doesn't support this yet: https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/issues/2895

Answer (score 0):

The following *Wikipedia* article has both *mass* and *radius*.
*[Wikipedia – List of Solar System objects by size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size)*.

Here is a *regex* scrape.

The *radius* is in units of *km*, and the *mass* is in units of *kg-10<sup>21</sup>*.
The additional field there is the error, ±.

And, *Saturn* includes a comment for the *radius*, *"136775 for A Ring"*.

```py
{
    'Sun': { 'r': [ 695508, 0 ], 'm': [ 1989100000, 0 ] },
    'Jupiter': { 'r': [ 69911, 6 ], 'm': [ 1898187, 88 ] },
    'Saturn': { 'r': [ 58232, 6 ], 'm': [ 568317, 13 ] }, 
    'Uranus': { 'r': [ 25362, 7 ], 'm': [ 86813, 4 ] },
    'Neptune': { 'r': [ 24622, 19 ], 'm': [ 102413, 5 ] },
    'Earth': { 'r': [ 6371.0084, 0.0001 ], 'm': [ 5972.4, 0.3 ] },
    'Venus': { 'r': [ 6052, 1 ], 'm': [ 4867.5, 0.2 ] },
    'Mars': { 'r': [ 3389.5, 0.2 ], 'm': [ 641.71, 0.03 ] },
    'Mercury': { 'r': [ 2439.4, 0.1 ], 'm': [ 330.11, 0.02 ] }
}
```